# Not able to add JSON Data inside forEach loop using if condition on elements

Tags: javascript, json

Hi I am trying to add few conditional data from one JSON object to another.I am trying below code.Data is having JSON object.I am not getting any one in Data though i am getting correct value in Temp

```
const userData= data.rows;
    const claimsB = claimsB;
    let Temp = '';
    let Data = '';
    userData.forEach((element) => {
        if (element.value.A == claimsB.B){
            Temp = element;
            Data += Temp;
        }
        console.log(Temp);
    });
   console.log(Data);
```

Comment: It looks like the elements of `userData` are objects, but you're trying to add them to a string value (`Data`). That will not work. You should probably be building an *array*, not a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`let Temp = ''; and let Data = '';` specify that both "Temp" and "Data" are declared as empty strings

`Temp = element;` is assigning the "element" object to "Temp" variable
At this point, type of "Temp" is converted to `Object`

`Data += Temp;` is trying to append an object to a string.
At this point, type of "Data" is still `String`

As per your statement, you expect "Data" to be a JSON object but that is not the case.
Hence, when you try to `console.log(Data)` at the end of your snippet, you might be seeing `[object Object]...` instead of a JSON object.

Suggestion:
Declare "Data" as an array and push conditionally matching elements to this.
Your code will look like this:

```
const userData= data.rows;
let Data = [];
userData.forEach((element) => {
    if (element.value.A == claimsB.B){
        Data.push(element);
    }
    console.log(Temp);
});
console.log(Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to replace

`Data += Temp;`

with

`Data += JSON.stringify(Temp);`

Comment: it will not work as it will add it as a string not as a object